# Does Docker support SO_REUSEPORT for kernel 3.9+?

Tags: docker

Does docker support binding containers to public port on host using SO_REUSEPORT option ?

Usecase: We have haproxy running in docker and it binds to port 80 on host. We want to do automated A/B deploy for new version of proxy on the same host (Note proxy is running as docker container). One way to achieve this is to use SO_REUSEPORT so that we can deploy new version with old version running and slowly transition to the new version.)